# Is this C++ standard compliant : double bang on double e.g. !!(-0.0)

Tags: c++, double

Is the following line `!!(val)` standard compliant. i.e is this portable to other compilers and hardwares?

I have tested this with gcc & clang compilers and it works across multiple version. But is it guaranteed to be compliant?

```
#include<iostream>
bool isNonZero(double val) {
    return !!(val);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout <<  std::boolalpha << isNonZero(-0.0) << std::endl; 
    std::cout <<  std::boolalpha << isNonZero(0.0) << std::endl; 
    std::cout <<  std::boolalpha << isNonZero(1.001) << std::endl; 
    std::cout <<  std::boolalpha << isNonZero(-1.001) << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not-not x is just x. It's pointless is what it is. `return val` has the exact same effect.

Comment: @sweenish It's the same in this context. More generally, it requires an operand that can be contextually converted to `bool`. Yes, that same contextual conversion is performed by a `return` statement in a `bool` function. But, for example, `!!"hello"` is *not* generally equivalent to `"hello"`.

Comment: But `"hello"` evaluates to true, the exact same as `!!"hello"`. You are getting the bool conversion with or without the extraneous typing. I can give you that my comment doesn't highlight that subtle difference with regards to C++ where a bool and a string literal (for example) are not in fact the same. But my first sentence also isn't using code. Logically, not-not-x is just x. Therefore, in the code, returning val is equivalent. The double bang isn't making it any more readable. I doubt any extra assembly is getting generated, but that syntax simply isn't helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's portable.

The `!` operator's operand is contextually converted to `bool`, and it yields `true` if the result is `false`, `false` if the result is `true`. The second `!` reverses that. `!!` (which is parsed as two `!` operators, since there is no `!!` token) in effect normalizes its operand to `bool`, yielding `true` if the expression is non-zero, `false` if it's zero.

But in my opinion your function would more clearly be written as:

```
bool isNonZero(double val) {
    return val != 0;
}
```